# ssl configuration in checkout process of magento

Tags: checkout, ssl

i want to configure https in checkout process instead of whole site i perform the configuration like this
[image]

if i put the https in Unsecure  it is applying on whole site which i dont want i just want to enable https on checkout and login part of frontend and rest of site being with http i also try this module also but did not work
[image]

kindly help me in this prob thanx